# Parse C# string to hh:mm:ss

Tags: c#

Given two strings

```
string date = "02Mar13";
string duration = "03.20min";
```

How do I parse them to `DateTime` and show them in the following format

```
string date = "02 March 2013";
string duration = "00:03:20";
```

I went through the list [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) but no one match my requirements.

Comment: you can use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx). There should be plenty of examples on MSDN and StackOverflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to parse these using a [Custom Date and Time format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), and output using one as well:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date + duration, 
                                  "ddMMMyymm.ss'min'", 
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

string newDate = dt.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");
string newDuration = dt.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Things to note: I am using `'min'` to represent the `min` literal in the string - this is part of custom format strings, allowing inner string literals.

Answer (score 4):

```
string date = "02Mar13";
string duration = "03.20min";
DateTime newDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date + duration, "ddMMMyymm.ss\\min", null);

date = newDate.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");
duration = newDate.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
```

Comment: The `03.20` is minutes.seconds, not hours.minutes, as the desired output shows.

Comment: +1 for `\\min` , proves that there is something you learn everday on SO

Comment: @Default - The `\\ ` escapes to a `\ ` which in turn escapes the `m` so it will not be interpreted as an additional `m` for the minutes parsing. The `in` is ignored as both `i` and `n` are not custom format characters for dates and times.

Answer (score 1):

DateTime parsing is pretty much straightforward using [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(date, "ddMMMyy", null).ToString("dd MMMM yyyy"); // "02 March 2013"
```

As for the second part, if it is a *duration* semantically, then it is more suitable to use [TimeSpan.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.parseexact.aspx) (although it required some fiddling with format strings):

```
TimeSpan.ParseExact(duration, "mm\\.ss'min'", null).ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss"); // "00:03:20"
```

Answer (score 1):

How can produce the dateResult

```
        string date = "02Mar13";
        string duration = "03.20min";
        var mat=Regex.Match(duration, "(.+?)min");
        var dateResult = DateTime.ParseExact(date + mat.Groups[1].Value.Replace(".",":"), "ddMMMyyHH:mm", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: Regex is overkill here. Absolutely not required, when custom format strings can deal with the literal directly.

Comment: Yeah! Yours better.  I didn't know 'expression' usage,very well.Thank you. +1